# 7zip destination folder

Tags: additional-drivers, extract

Suppose I am extracting zip files using:

```
7z e *.zip -o*
```

Now I have a folder with more zip files in it

How can I create a 7z archive (using the original zip filename) from those folders

Ex: extracting file1.zip would give folder, folder, folder...

I want to create a 7z archive that contains folder, folder, folder with the file1.zip name

I guess what I want to do is create a variable to store the folder names that come from the extraction part, and re-use that to the 7z a $folder but I don't know what the variable should be: folder=-o*? I don't think that would be correct. Could someone help here?

Regards,
Brian